# How can I suspend a process when other starts? (Python, Linux)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, xbmc

I have a device which automatically runs XBMC when it turns on. One of the menu options opens Google Chrome, and when that occurs, I want that XBMC stays suspended in background.
How can I do that? Should I use a daemon, an event listener? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: write a simple script daemon which does continously check if chrome has been started. if yes then send singal SIGTSTP to the xmbc process and when chrome stops it again sends signal SIGCONT to resume the xmbc

Comment: thank you, that's more or less what I was thinking :)